# onActivityResult() is not called with the correct intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, onactivityresult

It's been some days now that I'm trying to solve my problem but I haven't found a solution yet. At least I figured out how to describe my problem and already tried around a lot.

I'm starting Activity B from Activity A by startActivityForResult and expecting the Activity to send back a result. Activity B on the other hand starts Activity C by startActivityResult and depending on the result it receives it restarts itself. After restarting itself 2 times Activity B triggers onActivityResult of Activity A with the wrong intent.

If it restarts itself only once the correct Intent is transferred. This is how I call Activity B:

```
private void startB() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("uniqueID", "A triggers B");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

In Activity B I want to return back to A when 'currentRound > maxRound' and 'currentLevel < maxLevel' with maxRound being 2 after having received a result from Activity C, that is in the 'onActivityResult' - method of Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

/* Here is some code that depending on what result from Activity C was increases or decreases currentLevel and currentRound */

    if (currentRound > maxRound || currentLevel > maxLevel) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("uniqueID", "B triggers A on Result");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("currentLevel", currentLevel);
            intent.putExtra("currentRound", currentRound);
            intent.putExtra("uniqueID", "B triggers B");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

When I set maxRound=1 the correct intent is received by the onActivityResult method of Activity A. I checked this by putting

```
intent.putExtra("uniqueID", "B triggers B " + currentLevel +     currentRound);
```

I'm not quite sure but I think that after the onActivityResult in Activity B is called for the first time and it restarts Activity B after calling finish(), this call of the method sets the Result to be returned to onActivityResult in Activity A as soon as Activity B is not visible any more. That's why setResult after the second time Activity B restarts itself doesn't have any influence any more.

Does anybody have an idea how this can be solved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: all this restarts are very complicated. I think when you are restarting you activity, you can just call startActivity() and not "forResult" one. Can you describe what are you going to achive?

Comment: look at your else part you finish() activity before starting intent, so startActivity(intent) not work.. put finish() at the last of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, here is what I'm trying to do: Activity B speaks some digits and calls Activity C for the user to make an input of what he/she has heard. Then this Activity sends a result back to Activity B, onActivityResult is called where it is decided if the input was correct the next sequence of numbers is spoken etc. if the user is wrong twice the experiment is ended. @SagarChavada I've tried what you suggested but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What do you think about this 'solution/idea': have a single Activity and multiple fragments for the different Views; then Activity contains all information and I don't need to exchange data between activities that I've transformed to fragments.